# How to run EJB module in TomEE using tomcat server adapter in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, ejb, apache-tomee

Currently, I knows there is no separate server adapter for `TomEE` to configure in `Eclipse` so we have to use existing `tomcat adapter`.

EJB module is not detecting `TomEE` server to run in `eclipse` if I configure `TomEE` using `tomcat adapter`

see below screen shot. tomee is not listing
[image]

So is there any way to run `EJB module` in `TomEE` using `eclipse`?

Comment: Just deploy the application and run the server :s You don't need to "run" anything, EJBs are not standalone applications, there is nothing about them that you can run.

Comment: TomEE is an enterprise application server it already has support for EJB and many other JSRs, Note: Tomcat and TomEE are different

Comment: TomEE(configured using tomcat adapter) is not showing if I try to Run AS -> Run on Server in next window

Comment: http://tomee.apache.org/tomee-and-eclipse.html

Comment: Yes i know the differences between both but now i want to run EJB module in tomee server

Comment: What is the error when you try to deploy it?

Comment: Bilbo, please see the attachment

Comment: See this video it has the same thing which you want to do : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lr8pxEACVRI

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94089/discussion-between-bilbo-baggins-and-sasikumar-murugesan).

Comment: TomEE needs ears to be deployed in "apps" rather than "webapps" but I am not exactly sure how to configure that in Eclipse